# Hide the URL bar in Android Webkit

Tags: android, webkit, jqtouch, iui

This doesn't seem to work in jqTouch or iUI. But I know it's possible because it works on my Droid when I go to deviantart.com . Anyone know how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'm gonna answer my own question here. I added this bit of jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function() { setTimeout(scrollTo,200,0,1) });
```

The timeout appears to be necessary. On my Droid, the document is not yet ready to scroll when the DOMContentLoaded event is fired.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried firing the function on window.load and on pageAnimation events?

```
// Hide URL bar when loading the first page
$(window).load( function() {
    setTimeout(scrollTo,200,0,1);
});

// ...and on every subsequent request handled by jQTouch
$(document).delegate("body", "pageAnimationStart pageAnimationEnd", function() {
    setTimeout(scrollTo,200,0,1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a webkit i'm assuming that you have created an on create method, create a class below it that looks something like this

```
private class CallBack extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {

            browser.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

    }   
}
```

declare a webviewclient, and a webview when creating the parent class

```
WebView browser;
WebViewClient browserClient;
```

that should keep your app from opening an external browser.

Went through the same problem when i was starting my app project, so I hope this helps